# Create random time series with shifts predetermined

Tags: r, random, time, time-series

I'm trying to create some random time series with shifts (or gap) along the series.

Some with normal distribution and the others with non-normal distribution (Log normal for example).
For both I have to decide:

- the numbers of the shifts
- the positions of each shifts
- the magnitudes of each shifts
- the lenght between a shift and another one

The data is 130 years length (monthly) with all positive numbers (because I want to simulate natural abundance time series).
I hope with a picture you can understand better.

[image]

I read in other questions some methods for example I tried with `arima.sim()` but I think that I can't put my shifts.

Answer (score 1):

Why not break your time series into multiple time series, each of which represents a particular shift that you want.  If you do this then you can create them with `arima.sim()` as you discussed.

You can then append these time series vectors together to create your required vector.

This is typically how I'd attack such a problem when trying to insert a step like shock into financial time series data.

Comment: Thanks, I thought to do this, is it possible to find a loop command?